# How to stop auto clicker upon pressing a Key

Tags: java, keylistener, awtrobot

```
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {



        if ( e.getKeyChar() == 'x' ) {
            Clicking = true;
        }
            try {
                if(Clicking == true)
                robot = new Robot();
                while (true) {
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    robot.delay(1000);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    if(e.getKeyChar() == 'b'){
                        Clicking = false;
                    }
                } } catch(AWTException awtException) {
                awtException.printStackTrace();

               }
            }
```

I'm trying to make it so whenever I press b the autoclicker stops it works when I press x but doesn't stop after I press b

Comment: What auto clicker? Is this a Swing application? Are you clicking on an external application? Key events are only passed to the Swing component that has focus. When using Swing the proper solution is to use `Key Bindings`. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Did you got it working? Was also interested if my suggestion helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the mechanism on the core while, I don't say it is bad, although what about assigning it to methods like run_it and stop_it? Or just, perform_the_click (that cud be more simply).

"I'm trying to make it so whenever I press b the autoclicker stops it works when I press x but doesn't stop after I press b".

I seriously don't see it has sense, try using commas, thus it makes it non-understandable for the community.

Please show more about the project, where does the Clicking just came from?

Answer (score 0):

You require another thread to listen to your 'b's click. Because it is running on the current thread it blocks listening to inputs.

An idea of something like this:

```
 if(e.getKeyChar() == 'x' ) {
   if(robot == null) {
      robot = new Robot(someObjectIWantToBringOver);
      Thread thread = new Thread(robot);
      thread.start();
   }
 }
 if(e.getKeyChar() == 'b' ) {
    if(robot != null) {
       robot.stop();
       robot = null;
    }
 }
```

//In your Robot class

```
 class Robot implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private final Object xyz;

    public Robot(Object abc??) {
      this.xyz = abc;
    }
 ...
    public void run() {
       while(running) {
          try{
            xyz.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            xyz.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
          }catch(Exception e) {}
       }
   }

   public void stop() {
       running = false;
   }
 }
```

Looks like a fun project. Have fun!